# Where can I find system log information on OS X Lion 10.7.5 for System Preferences changes?

Tags: system-settings

Suppose I navigate to System Preferences and make a simple change (say I turn off BlueTooth).

Is it logged somewhere in the syslog? In other words, is there a log file somewhere on the file system that keeps track of what was written to the System Preferences plist file?

The main reason I am asking this question is because I would like to know when certain things were set in the System Preferences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find that information in the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist`

They will open in TextEdit, but hard to read. So you might need to [read this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/5288/46541) for help with Plist readers.

you can also see the plist changes in the:

Console (by typing pref in the search window)

[image: syst pref]

While the Console is up to the moment reporting it will only report issues not the successful execution.